# SWRevealViewController - How to elegantly make the menu disappear with a tap on FrontViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, swrevealviewcontroller

I wish for the menu to be hidden when the front view controller is tapped on while the menu is visible.

I need to know an elegant solution to this that doesn't get me to add a gesturerecognizer on all my viewcontrollers

Comment: I think the gesturerecognizer thing is the most "elegant" solution I have found. Try https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/63 if you haven't seen it already

Comment: you can try this: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/swrevealviewcontroller-disabling-user-interaction-when-toggled-to-rearview/

Answer (score 0):

SWRevealViewController provides you with a tap gesture controller which is ready to use. So you can simply add it to your front controller :
`self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())`

Moreover, if you want to do it only once, you can create a controller which adds this gesture recognizer, and then inherit from this class. Example in Swift :

```
class YourFrontViewControllerParentClass : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let revealController = self.revealViewController() {
            // add the tap gesture recognizer to the front view (RootViewController) so that the sidebar menu closes when the user taps the front view when the side menu is closed.
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }
}

class YourFrontViewControllerChildClass1 : YourFrontViewControllerParentClass {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // specific stuff
    }
}

class YourFrontViewControllerChildClass2 : YourFrontViewControllerParentClass {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // specific stuff
    }
}

class YourFrontViewControllerChildClass3: YourFrontViewControllerParentClass {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // specific stuff
    }
}
```